In automated testing what is the best approach for testing each field using positive and negative tests as well?
Let's say I have a popup which has 3 fields and I have dataproviders where I provide different combinations (positive and negative) of values to fill out the popup. There is also a boolean which indicates whether that set of dataproviders should result in success or error which I use for assertion.
The fields handle error maybe differently, like one is disabled if user role differs, one shows error if the user types in invalid form, etc.
Is this an overkill to use try block for each field on the popup?
If this is an overkill, what would be a better approach to test a lot of combinations of several fields?
I tried out the mentioned structure but I was thinking if there is a rule of thumb here.
 // Test field 1
            try {
                page.fill("#field1", "TestValue1");
                System.out.println("Field 1 test passed.");
            } catch (PlaywrightException e) {
                System.out.println("Field 1 test failed: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            // Test field 2
            try {
                page.fill("#field2", "TestValue2");
                System.out.println("Field 2 test passed.");
            } catch (PlaywrightException e) {
                System.out.println("Field 2 test failed: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            // Test field 3
            try {
                page.fill("#field3", "TestValue3");
                System.out.println("Field 3 test passed.");
            } catch (PlaywrightException e) {
                System.out.println("Field 3 test failed: " + e.getMessage());
            }


Are you using any testing framework like JUnit 5 or TestNG? Typically, in web UI automation it is expected that you'll pair up a testing framework along with the browser automation framework. The testing framework provides various options to structure your tests. For example, here is a JUnit 5 implementation from Playwright's official documentation page:
@Test
void shouldClickButton() {
    page.navigate("data:text/html,<script>var result;</script><button onclick='result=\"Clicked\"'>Go</button>");
    page.locator("button").click();
    assertEquals("Clicked", page.evaluate("result"));
}

You mark a method as a test method by applying @Test annotation. Then, you perform necessary actions in the method and at the end, you make an assertion whether the expected outcome is equal to the actual outcome.
If you are looking for a generic test automation framework using Playwright and Java, you can check this repository.

thank you yes I use test ng. The try block I provided is just a mock up like how to approach field validations one by one. I hope you can just understand the underlying problem I was thinking about. I need no code example, just the thinking
